# Вывод краткой и полной новости

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте. Я сохраняю новость, как html страницу. Точнее, просто набор текста и html тегов, например

```
<span style="color:red;">Hello world</span>
```

Хочу выводить полную и краткую новость на странице.
Но если в полной новости 10^6 символов то какой смысл выводить их всех. Вопрос состоит в том, как бы мне корректно вывести краткую новостью. Первое, что приходит в голову, это обрезать строку, но тогда получатся незакрытые html теги, что будут все портить.

Comment: новости стоит хранить без разметки и в базе данных. а страницы уже создавать на лету из этой информации, добавляя разметку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один вариант добавлять авто. "читать далее" http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/.
О нем можно почитать подробней на сайте, он умеет понимать как обрезать не нарушив теги.

Как выше сказали отдельное поле завести или обрезать строку по кол символов сколько надо вывести.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего добавлять "краткую новость" вручную, сделав для этого специальное поле.

Но если уж совсем лень и плевать на возможные косяки, то достать новость, вырезать теги через strip_tags и отрезать по первую через 100 символов точку.